# How can I get rid of GoogleVoiceAndVideoAccelSetup on Mac Os Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Can you please see the attached image:

[image]

I have no idea where these came from and I can not get rid of them.. The eject buttons next to them do not seem to do any work. This happened after Yosemite update.

Comment: 1) Could be a cache problem. If it is, a quick search for them (in Spotlight) should show nothing. 2) Try restarting (it may work). 3) If you recently installed google voice and video, then deleting the dmg or package file for the installer and emptying the trash and then ejecting should work. 4) Try relaunching Finder (option, cmd, esc) > Finder > Relaunch) - see if that works. 5) Go to Disk Utility, find the GoogleVoiceAndVideoAccelSetup image(s), click INFO and find the source.

Comment: 1) Nothing in search results.
2) Have rebooted multiple times. Still there.
3) Packages and dmgs are long gone
4) Relaunched. Still there.
5) They do not show in Disk Utility.

What dark magic is this?

Comment: @Brendonwbrown Same here, have no idea..

Comment: Same issue here,  any solution that worked?

Comment: @DanielBenedykt Not for me yet.

Comment: Koray, may I suggest that you accept an answer if you have found one that works for you? That way it will be clear whether a full uninstall or simply the folder cleanup is your preferred choice. As it stands now we have others speaking for you.

Comment: @MichaelGrant None of the answers work, they will always appear after a few days.

Comment: Interesting. I would assume a full uninstall would do it. But perhaps another Google updater reinstalls the codec.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Of course full uninstall will make them disappear but it is not a resolution since I want to use Google Hangouts but I do not want the multiple volumes in my computer.

Comment: Ah, good. Thanks for the clarification. Not everyone who has this problem is worried about losing Google Hangout capability. The answers that offer the full uninstall will be useful to such folks, like me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the terminal to go to /private/tmp, and you'll find a set of folders which name starts with 2014*, in my case I had 20141118101236 and 20141117152211.

It seems that each of these folders match with every "zombie" Google volume displayed in finder. I was about to delete both folders, but before deleting them I decided to open the tmp folder with finder by doing "open ." from the terminal, and once the finder window popped up the "zombie" folders from My Mac got deleted automatically, it must have been a cache problem.

Comment: I had to use sudo to delete these, then kill and restart Finder to clear them. So like this:


`sudo rm -rf /private/tmp/2014*

killall Finder`

Comment: I deleted them all and restarted. Twice on different days. They keep coming back.

Comment: @tubedogg same here, they are always back.

Answer (score 14):

Same problem here.

Found and deleted `/Library/Caches/com.google.SoftwareUpdate.0`
Restarted finder (Alt + Right Click on finder icon then Click Relaunch)

Result:  All GoogleVoiceAndVideoAccelSetup* volumes removed.

Reference:
OS X 10.10 on a late 2009 iMac

Comment: I did this then 'killall Finder' (as I was on the command-line anyway), did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I simply quit Chrome and then relaunched Finder. Seemed to work fine without clearing the cache.

Answer (score 9):

I found this on the Google support website, which worked for me on OS X (although had to reboot to finally remove the extra mounted volumes):

> **To uninstall in Windows**:
>
> Click **Start** > **Settings** > **Control Panel**. Double-click **Add or Remove
>   Programs**. Scroll down to find **Google Talk** plugin. Click **Remove**, then
>   Yes, then Finish.
>
> **To uninstall in Mac OS X**:
>
> Open **Finder** and then open the **Terminal** application. Copy and paste the
>   following command into the window:
>
> /Library/Application\  Support/Google/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller
>
> Press **Enter** on your keyboard.

Comment: As has been mentioned in comments to other answers this will uninstall the service, which is not the point of the question.

Comment: Comments on other answers, by other users, does not change the original question. If you go back and read the original question it simply states "how do I get rid of it".

Comment: Uninstalling the service is quite clearly overkill for this problem. He could also "get rid of it" by uninstalling OS X or throwing his Macbook into a river. By mentioning the Eject buttons it should be obvious that he's just asking how to get rid of the phantom mounted disks.

Comment: Quite clearly you are right because you are awesome. I'm going to go down to the river and fish out his MacBook now.

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable solution, and precisely the one I wanted for this very problem. +1.

Answer (score 4):

Open your user Library folder (and possibly the computer’s main Library folder too, for good measure).

From within the Library folder, find & open the Application Support folder.

From within the Application Support folder, find and open the Google folder.

Inside the Google folder, you may find a Google Talk Plugin Uninstaller app. Launch the Uninstaller (by double-clicking on it), and you should get a message that the Google Talk Plugin has been uninstalled. Reboot.

That might solve the problem!

Comment: I do not think he wishes to uninstall the service. I too have these garbage directories in my system root.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to uninstall on Mac, you can run this command in your terminal:

```
/Library/Application\ Support/Google/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller
```

Comment: This is the 'faster' way of doing it rather than going through folders one by one.

Comment: The point is not uninstalling the service, it's getting rid of the garbage directories/mountpoints in the root directory.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me and fixes some other minor misc issues. absolutely safe to try.

`$ rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder ; killall Finder`

good luck!

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: This appears to remove the finder's cache, and then kill the Finder. OSX will restart it automatically. It's actually Google that's creating the mounts, not Apple -- deleting the com.google.SoftwareUpdate.0 mentioned below by Ari Moor did the trick for me instead. Then killall Finder.

Answer (score 1):

My Mac listed those volumes, too. Just restart Finder and they are gone.

Press <kbd>alt</kbd> and right click Finder icon to restart Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it just a cache error and opening the library in finder fixes it. In terminal type:

```
cd  /private/tmp
open .
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://support.google.com/chat/answer/161994?hl=en if you want to uninstall the plugin GoogleVoiceAndVideo.

Comment: I do not want to uninstall the plugin.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.